# Update bound control from own background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I have WPF with MVVM app. ViewModel and View are connected. Controls from View are bound to ViewModel, and ViewModel inherits INotifyChanged. Simple control update in ViewModel works fine.

I'd like to create some info class that contains some info fields. Next I want to create my own thread that maps fields from Info class to fields in ViewModel that updates View. Object of Info class will be used as arg of function called in ViewModel.

```
private int someControl;
public SomeControl {
    get{return someControl;}
    set 
    {
        someControl = value;
        OnPropChanged("SomeControl");
    }

private InfoClass info = new InfoClass();
Thread thread = null;

public ViewModel()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(update));
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.start();

    someLongFunction(info);
}

private void update()
{
    SomeControl = info.someField;
    thread.sleep(1000);
    update();
}
```

What should I add or change to get update periodically? Now, update is only when someLongFunction ends its job.

Comment: I don't get you entirely... What do you want to do? Do you want to periodically update your view?

Comment: Indeed, I want that funcionality:)

Comment: Calling your update-method recursively as you do there will eventually create a stackoverflow! Well, you can define timers in `System.Threading.Timer` or you'll have to work with thread-synchronization-primitives (`Mutex` and `Event`). And this is to happen while `someLongFunction` is running?

Comment: I didn't get stackoverflow, but maybe I had too short app run time. I have to add, that if I write SomeControl += 1 instead of SomeControl = info.someField; it works fine.

Comment: I didn't say you GOT stackoverflow, but you WILL eventually get it, calling your method recursively over and over again.

Comment: I will try to do it with Timer. I wonder too why SomeControl += 1 works fine instead of SomeeControlee = info.somerfield. Do you know something about this?

Comment: This is because you are assigning a new reference to your object, the getter/setter is not called this way!

Answer (score 0):

If what you actually want is continuous view updates then you don't have to create a thread for that because then you will have to make those updates on the Dispatcher thread (UI Thread). Instead you can use the [DispatcherTimer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) which was built exactly for this kind of situation where you can provide an interval and the DispatcherTimer will call your method periodically at that interval and will do that automatically on the Dispatcher Thread.